# Fetching data which are not available in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
================= Customer Table =============
# customer
Code    Description 
301     Customer 1
302     Customer 2
386     Customer 3
387     Customer 4
390     Customer 5
391     Customer 6
392     Customer 7
```

I am using below query

```
select * from customer
where code not in (310, 350, 301, 302);
```

From the above query it will fetch below data

```
Code    Description 
386     Customer 3
387     Customer 4
390     Customer 5
391     Customer 6
392     Customer 7
```

But actually I want get output as

```
310 
350
```

Means which data are not available which we are putting in where condition.

I don't want to create another table to achieve this.

Please share some idea.

Answer (score 5):

Use a subquery to create a derived table with these values, and then LEFT JOIN it to the real table.

```
SELECT t1.code
FROM (SELECT 310 AS code UNION SELECT 350 UNION SELECT 301 UNION SELECT 302) AS t1
LEFT JOIN customer AS c ON c.code = t1.code
WHERE c.code IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71360c/1)

Comment: In question I have putted very limited value. But actually I have 200 records. Which is not possible to put those value in union clause manually. Is there any other way

Comment: You can create the query dynamically using a programming language.

Comment: Any solution will require putting all 200 numbers into the query somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 310 AS code UNION SELECT 350 UNION SELECT 301 UNION SELECT 302) AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM customer
             WHERE code = t1.code)
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71360c/5)